# Postgres 9.6 on AWS with frequent "could not connect to server: Operation timed out"

Tags: networking, postgresql, amazon-rds

I've just set up a new Postgres 9.6 on a db.t2.small with 100gb SSD in AWS Sydney region.  I can connect to it through psql and pgAdmin using the master user and password, so it has been setup correctly, and the security groups allow access. But after running a few commands it throws:

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
>       Is the server running on host "xyz.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.xxx.xxx.xxx)
>   and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

So given that I can connect and can issue commands like `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` successfully, why would it drop the connection so frequently?

I am trying to restore a 300mb dump file, but it drops connection even when running basic SELECTs, or refreshing the object list in pgAdmin.  When attempting a restore, it drops connection in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: You're connecting to your PG instance over the public internet? Or from another host in EC2?

Comment: Connecting direct from my workstation.  Thats actually not a bad idea, I could try to connect from one of my EC2 instances in the same VPC.

Comment: Connecting to *any* database server over the public internet is a very bad idea, for both security and performance reasons. Give it a try from an EC2 instance in the same VPC (you *are* using VPC, right?). If the problem is solved (it very likely will be), then you know where the issue lies (your internet connection).